# Was Tony Curtis the inspiration for the voice of Top Cat?

Tags: cartoon

Was Tony Curtis the inspiration for the voice of Top Cat (Top Cat Cartoon - Hanna-Barbera)?
Were any other Top Cat characters inspired by actors of the day?

Comment: Is Top Cat science fiction or fantasy? (Note that having anthropomorphic animals [does not make something SFF](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5117/82909).)

Comment: I always thought Top Cat was a bit 'Phil Silvers Bilko' in voice and manner

Comment: @Danny3414 that is explicit. TC is animated Bilko.

Comment: Yep, you're both right. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Cat

I saw Tony Curtis in a Roseanne episode and when he spoke I heard Top Cat despite TC's con-cat (con-man) personality was a Bilko thing.